# Do we need two separate StandardScaler for the features and target?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So what I've understand is that `StandardScaler().fit_transform(X, y)` does not change the target feature (`y`). Meanwhile, for some algorithms (such as weight-based or distance-based) we also need to scale the target feature.

My question is, do we have to implement two `StandardScaler`, one for the features and another for the target feature? I imagine we can also use it before splitting the training dataset into `X` and `y`, but wonder how we might then use it on deployment, as we wouldn't have `y`.

```py
# --- creating pipelines
transformer_x = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy='constant'), 
    StandardScaler())

transformer_y = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy='constant'), 
    StandardScaler())

# --- development
model.fit(transformer_x.fit_transform(X_train), transformer_y.fit_transform(y_train))
```

```py
# --- 
# sometime later in deployment
saved_model.predict(transformer_x.transform(new_data))
```

Also as a side question, is there any condition where we might not need to do standardisation for weight/distance-based algorithms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *Do we have to implement two `StandardScaler`, one for the features and another for the target feature?*

In general it's not necessary to scale target features. The only case it may be beneficial is in some cases of NN. Check this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re) for further information related.

- *Also as a side question, is there any condition where we might not need to do standardization for weight/distance-based algorithms?*

Standardization always is beneficial for your training phase in general terms. Maybe you should avoid it if you need some type of interpretation of the parameter. Again, here I provided an interesting [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189652/is-it-a-good-practice-to-always-scale-normalize-data-for-machine-learning).

Answer (score 2):

The most semantically correct way to do this is to use `TransformedTargetRegressor` with the scaler as `transformer` and the pipeline--with the scaler for `X` (and any other preprocessing for `X`) and the final regressor--as `regressor`.  One additional perk compared to what you've provided: the predicted target will be re-scaled back to the original scaling.